# method ambiguity when declaring a type in Go

Tags: go

I'm learning go and came across this piece of code on go tour:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type MyFloat int

func (f MyFloat) Abs() float64 {
    if f < 0 {
        return float64(-f)
    }
    return float64(f)
}

func (f MyFloat) run() string{
    fmt.Println("This is called")
    return "Hey there"
    }

func main() {
    f := MyFloat(-math.Sqrt2)
    fmt.Println(f.Abs())
    fmt.Println(f.run())
}
```

Here we declare a type named MyFloat and return type is float64. I was thinking that I can declare methods which only returns float64. I declared a method named `run()` in the above case which returns string. How is this possible? Why can't I just declare the type with no specific return type like this `type MyFloat`?

[Example in Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K33MHexzlL)

Comment: What is the point (use case) of declaring a `type` without any underlying representation (e.g. `type MyFloat` in your question)?

Comment: @putu ok. Then how did the `run()` work?

Comment: `run()` is a method not *a type declaration*, thus the *rule* is different. Method/function may not returning any value, e.g. `func main()` in the question. It is also possible to return value(s) having any type (not limited to `float64`), e.g. `string, float64, MyFloat`, etc... Note that *type declaration* **does not** return a type. It creates user defined type in which the underlying representation is given *after* the type name (`MyFloat`'s underlying type is `float64`).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing types and methods. As putu already menitioned in a comment, types don't "return" anything. In a kind of handwavy way most types are just data structures that you can attach methods to*.

Another way to write the methods in your example is this:

```
// func (f MyFloat) Abs() float64 {
func Abs(f MyFloat) float64 {
    if f < 0 {
        return float64(-f)
    }
    return float64(f)
}

// func (f MyFloat) run() string {
func run(f MyFloat) string {
    fmt.Println("This is called")
    return "Hey there"
}
```

Note that the function bodies are no different at all. The difference is just in how you call these functions. Semantically they are equivalent. The receiver of a method becomes the implicit first argument to a function.

[*] This ignores function types, which don't hold data. net/http.HandlerFunc is a prominent example in the standard library.

```
type HandlerFunc func(ResponseWriter, *Request)
```